# Where do files go when you AirDrop them on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipod, airdrop

Where do AirDrop files go when I transfer them between an iPad, iPhone and iPod? I AirDropped some Google Docs from my iPad to my iPhone but nothing happened; where did my files go? The file was a list of tools.

Comment: What app is sending which sort of file from the iPad?

Comment: AirDrop from iPad Google docs to iPhone

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Just select the edit button to explain that you're sending from Google Docs. Also, what  _kind_ of file you send matters on how the receiving iOS device will handle it.

Comment: This is still an annoying challenge - it isn't often obvious which app on an iOS device corresponds with a file type.  I transferred some m4v files (video) and they ended up in Photos - not the TV app where I would expect them.  If there are any problems with transfer, then it is really hard to figure out.  But with Google Docs - why use AirDrop at all - they are available through Google Drive on the iOS device already surely.

Answer (score 4):

On iOS, AirDropped files open immediately and automatically in the app registered to handle them via AirDrop. If no such app exists, those files simply disappear.

Typically, if you AirDrop a document using one app, you’ll want to have the same app installed on the receiving iOS device.

Answer (score -2):

I Found them... check your downloads folder!

Comment: Your answer is Mac based. The question is about iOS!